# Time and Date Calculations

Tags: swift, nsdateformatter

Using date format "EEEE:dd:MMM:HH:mm" returns the correct date and time, however, the day of the week is incorrect. For example a 750 nautical mile voyage conducted at 7.5 knots will take 100 hours. If I use my code to calculate the arrival time using a start of, say, Friday 1 Nov at 12:00 it returns Sunday 5 Nov at 16:00. Time and date are correct but day of the week is not. Should be Tuesday.

```
 @IBAction func Calculate(_ sender: UIButton) {


    let userCalendar = Calendar.current

    let dateMakerFormatter = DateFormatter()

    dateMakerFormatter.dateFormat = "EEEE:dd:MMM:HH:mm"

    let distance = (Distance.text! as NSString).floatValue
    let speed = (GndSpd.text! as NSString).floatValue

    let calcDT = ((distance / speed) * 3600)


    if var date = dateMakerFormatter.date(from: (DTG.text!)) {
        date = dateMakerFormatter.date(from: (DTG.text!))!


        var timeAdj = DateComponents()
        timeAdj.second = Int(calcDT)

    if var adj = userCalendar.date(byAdding: timeAdj, to: date) {
        adj = userCalendar.date(byAdding: timeAdj, to: date)!

        CalcDTG.text = dateMakerFormatter.string(from: adj)

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Day is `d`, not `D`. Case matters in date format specifiers.

Comment: You need to update your question with actual input, actual results, and expected results.

Comment: An example would be 750 nautical miles at 7.5 knots would be 360,000 seconds. i.e. four days and four hours. If I use the code to add this to, say, Friday 1 Nov at 12:00 it should return Tuesday 5 Nov at 16:00. It actually returns Sunday 5 Nov at 16:00. The day of the week is incorrect

Comment: Please indicate that this question is solved. Then post a new question with all relevant details to your new issue.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `d` for Day, not `D`

```
 dateMakerFormatter.dateFormat = "EEEE:dd:MMM:HH:mm"
```

[**DateFormatter**](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/dateformatter)

Comment: Million thanks! So simple when you know how. Program works well now.

Comment: This code now returns the correct date and time but the incorrect day of the month. For example  a distance of 750 nautical miles at 7.5 knots is 100 hours i.e. four days and four hours. If I run the code for Friday 1 Nov 12:00 it returns Sunday 5 Nov 16:00. It should be Tuesday? The date and time is correct.

Answer (score 0):

You can't say the day of the week is incorrect when you're not giving a year.

The date formatter seems to ignore the day of the week when creating a date:

```
let dateMakerFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateMakerFormatter.dateFormat = "EEEE:dd:MMM:HH:mm" 
let date = dateMakerFormatter.date(from: "Friday:01:Nov:12:00")!
print(date) -> 2000-11-01 12:00:00 +0000    
print(dateMakerFormatter.string(from: date)) -> Wednesday:01:Nov:12:00
```

Hey presto, you're now in the year 2000, where 5 November did fall on a Sunday. 
The important takeaway you need is that *you should never, ever, ever, use strings to pass around date values in your code*. Use `Date`. If you're getting a date from an API response, change it to a date on ingestion. If you're getting one from user entry, use a date picker or other control. If you're getting one from a string the user is typing in, I'd politely suggest you're making unnecessary work for yourself, but do make sure you fill in all the details the user doesn't give you.

Comment: Thanks. The inclusion of the year has fixed it.